# QGIS 3.16 cursor jumps out of screen when reshaping features

Tags: qgis-3, editing, cursor

when I'm reshaping features my cursor sometimes jumps out of screen (see gif). This error occurs only when clicking on certain vertices but I can't find any pattern. When I save and restart QGIS it works again on the exact same vertex. Anyone has an idea how to avoid this? Haven't found the bug anywhere else...

[image: cursor dislocation]

Answer (score 1):

It might be caused by invalid geometry on the layer you're editing. Try running 'Fix geometries' from the processing toolbox and seeing if that fixes your issue.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helps in most cases.